# Upper limit of bugs in a given program

Tags: language-agnostic

Is there an upper limit to the number of bugs contained in a given program?  If the number of instructions are known, could one say the program cannot contain more than 'n' bugs?  For example, how many bugs could the following function contain?

```
double calcInterest(double amount) {
    return -O.07 / amount;
}
```

A parser would count four terms in the function, and I could count these errors:

- wrong number syntax
- wrong interest rate (business requirements error)
- wrong calculation (should be multiply)
- Potential divide by zero

Clearly the number of bugs is not infinite given a finite number of instructions.  Alternatively, one could say the function accepts 2^64 inputs, and of those, how many produce the correct output.  However, is there any way to formally prove an upper limit?

Comment: What do you define as one instruction?

Comment: Uhh, there's a lot more than 2^8 = 256 doubles!?

Comment: You use the words "Bug" and "Error" as equivalent. There are syntax errors caught by the parser, runtime errors (bugs), logic errors(bugs) and design errors (defects). My definitions may not match yours but the issues and how they are detected are different. When and what you count as a bug will change the ultimate answer to your question. There are at least two separate "bug" counts for your question, errors in source code that will stop the program from even being run and those that occur at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If bug is **"a requirement not met by the program"**, then there is no limit on the number of bugs (per line or otherwise), since there is no limit on the number of requirements.

```
print "hello world"
```

Might contain a million bugs. It doesn't create a pink elephant. I leave it to the reader to come up with 999999 other requirements not satisfied by this program.

Comment: "It doesn't create a pink elephant". If there's no newline at the end of the file, then it *might* create a pink elephant (undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 2):

Number of instructions have nothing to do with whether the program does what the user wants it to do. I mean, look at how poorly GCC does balancing my check book. Buggy as all get out, down right useless!

Answer (score 1):

This would all depend on how you define a 'bug'.

If you define a program as a function from some input to some output, and a specification as a definition of that function, and a bug as any difference in output from the specification on a given input, then yes, you can conceivably have countably infinite bugs - however this is a somewhat useless definition of a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The upper limit is the number of states your program can be in.  Since this number is finite on real machines you could number the states from 1 to n.  For each state you could label if this state is a bug or not.  So yes, but even a small program having 16 bytes of memory has 2^128 states and the problem of analyzing all the different states is intractable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a theoretical upper limit for bugs, but for all but the most trivial programs it is very nearly impossible to calculate, although [engines such as Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/) do give it the old college try.

Comment: What would this theoretical limit be?

Comment: You mean for your trivial application?  Let's see...how many ways can you have a syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

Law of programming:

```
"If You will find all compile-time bugs, then n logical ones are still hidden, waiting to surprise You at run-time."
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you count bugs, which leads me to say "nope, no limit." I don't know about you, but I can **easily** write several bugs in the same line of code. For instance, how many bugs are in this Java code? :-P

```
public int addTwoNumbers(int x, String y)
{{
    z == x + y;
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As little as one if the bug is significant enough.